# Как записать результат асинхронного метода в self.connect в __init__

Tags: python, ооп, sqlite, asyncio

```
class RepoBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = # тут результат await get_connec()
    async def get_connect(self) -> aiosqlite.Connection:
        con = await aiosqlite.connect(self.path)
        return con
```

Как результат этой функции записать в `self.con` в `__init__`? Или можно по другому?

Answer (score 1):

Именно так, как вы хотите вызвать асинхронный метод из `__init__` не получится - `await` в `__init__` использовать нельзя, т.к. это синхронный метод, и асинхронным он не должен быть (попытка сделать его асинхронным приведет к ошибке `TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'coroutine'` при создании объекта).

В простых случаях можно просто в асинхронной функции создавать объект, потом от него же вызывать асинхронный метод:

```
class RepoBase:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        
    async def get_connect(self) -> aiosqlite.Connection:
        con = await aiosqlite.connect(self.path)
        return con


async def something():
    connect = await RepoBase(path).get_connect()
```

Если дополнительно требуется освобождение ресурсов, можно превратить ваш класс в асинхронный менеджер контекста, использовать его с конструкцией `async with`, в самом классе возвращать соединение через метод `__aenter__`, в `__aexit__` освобождать ресурсы:

```
class RepoBase:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
    
    async def get_connect(self) -> aiosqlite.Connection:
        con = await aiosqlite.connect(self.path)
        return con
    
    async def __aenter__(self) -> aiosqlite.Connection:
        return await self.get_connect()

    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        # Тут можно добавить какой-то код,
        # который будет выполняться при выходе из блока async with
        pass


async def main():
    async with RepoBase() as connection:
        ...
        # Делаете что вам нужно с полученным соединением
```

Если нужно, чтобы из объекта можно было получать соединение несколько раз, и оно все время было одно и то же (не открывалось новое соединенеи), можно к методу `get_connect` прикрутить кэширование, например с помощью модуля [`async_lru`](https://github.com/aio-libs/async-lru):

```
import asyncio
import random
from async_lru import alru_cache


class RepoBase:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
    
    @alru_cache()
    async def get_connect(self):
        print("Obtained connection")
        con = random.randint(0, 1000)
        return con
    
    async def __aenter__(self):
        return await self.get_connect()
    
    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        pass
    
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        # При кэшировании равными будут объекты с одинаковым путём
        print("hashing")
        return hash(self.path)


async def main():
    repo_base = RepoBase(12312)
    print("Object created")
    async with repo_base as connection:
        print(connection)

    async with repo_base as connection:
        print(connection)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Вывод:

```
Object created
hashing
Obtained connection
324
hashing
324
```

---

По поводу запуска асинхронной функции из `__init__` через `asyncio.run` из соседнего ответа:

В этом коде `self.conn` будет заполнено в неопределенный момент. В идеале, асинхронная функция должна сохранить результат в `Future`, от которого потом нужно будет сделать `await`, чтобы получить результат, примерно так :

```
# ПОЛУРАБОЧИЙ КОД, НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ
class RepoBase:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.__connect_future = asyncio.Future()
        asyncio.run(self.init_connect())
    
    async def init_connect(self):
        con = random.randint(0, 1000)
        self.__connect_future.set_result(con)

    async def get_connect(self):
        return await self.__connect_future
```

Но с этим кодом будут возникать разные интересные проблемы, начиная с того, что
если объект будет создаваться из асинхронной функции, то вылетит с ошибкой `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`.

Для других вариантов создания объекта будут свои варианты отказа, которые можно долго и весело дебажить. Так что проще не смешивать синхронный и асинхронный код, особенно внутри `__init__`, а использовать самый первый вариант из этого ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Должно работать так:

```
self.con = await self.get_connect()
```

Насчет **инитов**, мне кажется не лучшей идеей держать там логику, но впрочем, чем черт не шутит, если используешь код по максимум, то почему нет если да?

```
import asyncio
import aiosqlite

class RepoBase:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.con = None
        asyncio.run(self.init_async())

    async def init_async(self):
        self.con = await self.get_connect()

    async def get_connect(self) -> aiosqlite.Connection:
        con = await aiosqlite.connect(self.path)
        return con
```

штош, господа, пробуем

Comment: Но, очевидно, из `__init__` это не будет работать, потому что `__init__` - синхронный метод, и асинхронным никогда не должен быть.

Comment: await никто не видит? После того как ```get_connect() ``` завершается, ```init_async()``` записывает результат в ```self.con ```

Comment: `await` можно использовать только в асинхронных методах, а `__init__` - синхронный (см. первый комментарий). Будет вот такая ошибка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBe68.png. Если бы так можно было, то думаю и не было бы такого вопроса.

Comment:  в данном случае ```__init__() ```запускает асинхронный метод ```init_async()```, с помощью ```asyncio.run() ```. время для проверить мою теорию.

Comment: В данном случае `__init__` не запускает никакой `init_async`. Только если явно через `asyncio.run()` запускать, само оно ничего не запустит. Но в итоге результат в conn в неопределенный момент появится. Лучше не извращаться, а просто вызвать await метода get_connect() не изнутри `__init__`, а отдельно.

Comment: Почему-бы не попробовать эксперименты с инитом?

Comment: Потому что это так себе идея, я уже написал выше